# Why does the count on multiple file input field in the form output 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a multiple file input form but when I leave the input as empty and run the count command on the input field then it gives 1 as value.

```
<form action="submit_post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input id="images" type="file" name="image[]"  title="Upload Images" class="upload" multiple="multiple"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn" />
</form>
```

and here is my submit_post.php file

```
<?php

echo count($_FILES['image']['name']);

?>
```

I need the value to be zero in order to write an if statement where the image input field is empty then don't execute a query, but it is executing the query even if I didn't select any file.

I have even tried to use 'empty' but still no luck as it is considering it as not empty.

Comment: check the file size `$_FILES['image']['size'] == 0`

Comment: when you submit the form, the file input field set the blank value. that's why count() method return 1. if you solve the problem you need to use client side validation using javascript or html required attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter the names before counting:

```
$numberOfFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['image']['name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also count your whole `$_FILES`

**Example :**

```
echo count($_FILES);
```

You should check `$_FILES` variable holding proper data.

**Example :**

```
var_dump($_FILES);

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
   $files = count($_FILES['image']); #Here is the count of files
}else{
    #No files to be uploads
}
```

**Example :**

```
$count = isset($_FILES['image'])? count($_FILES['image']) : 0; #Here is the count of files
```